# Access MVC application settings from layout page(s)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout, asp.net-mvc-5, web-config

I am trying to further help my organization's users know that the environment they are on is our test environment.  I have putting a setting in the application settings section of both the web.config and then transform(replace) that setting in the web.release.config.  All I want to do is switch our logo from it's normal color to a red variant.  Below is what I've tried and it always goes to the else statements option.

```
@if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"] == "PROD")
            {
                <img src="~/Content/Img/default/sru_logo.png" class="sruLogo" alt="" />
            }
            else if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"] == "PPRD")
            {
                <img src="~/Content/Img/default/sru_logo_test.png" class="sruLogo" alt="" />
            }
            else
            {
                <p>Not Working</p>
            }
```

I've tried using Context.Application["Environment"], System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"]

None of the above has worked and as I stated all I am trying to do is use a different image on my _Layout.cshtml file based on an application setting.

Answer (score 0):

try using round brackets instead of suqare

`System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Environment");`

Comment: i get a message from resharper that says: Proves access to configuration for client applications.  This class cannot be inherited.  Method, delegate or event is expected.  

When I try it anyways in the browser I get CS1955: Non-invocable member 'ConfigurationManager.AppSettings' cannot be used like a method

Comment: Can you make sure that the web.config file is copied to the "Debug" or "Release" folder when the project was Built, maybe it is not copied and it contains old values.